# Jumping from Inline1 to Inline2 using a CountDown in the same HTML

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a 1st Inline table with a 3 seconds count down and when it reaches to 0 (zero) I would like to load a 2nd Inline block by itself. When counter === 0.

It is a game and you have 3 secs to choose the answer per block, you either click or let the game take you the next block once the timer gets to zero.

If click on the link, it does take me to 2nd block. The problem is combining the countdown and transitioning to a 2nd or 3rd block by itself.

I've tried several things but with no success. Any idea on how to fix my code? I will really appreciate it. Hopes this makes sense.

HTML:

```
<button class='inline' href="#Set1" onclick="CountDown()">Start here...</button>

<div style='display:none'>
   <div id='GameSet1'>
       <table width="100%"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <a class="Set2" href="#">Click here to open 2nd Set</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Time left: <div id="count1">3</div></b>
                 </td>             
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='GameSet2'>
        <table width="100%"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <a class="SetN" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Time left: <div id="countN">3</div></b>
                 </td>              
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code here when (counter === 0) does not work.

CODE: (Uses jQuery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inline").colorbox({
    inline: true,
    width: "1000",
    height: "850"
    });    
});
function CountDown() { 
    var counter = 3;                                
    setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count1");
        span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        $(".Set2").colorbox({
            inline:true, 
            href:"#GameSet2"
        });
    clearInterval(counter);
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: could u provide a fiddle mate..??It would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you have a set of panels and you want each panel to be displayed for 3 seconds unless an link is clicked. If this is the case, I have a solution. Unfortunately, my example does not work inside jsFiddle because everything is surrounded in a function. Also, I decided to not use jQuery because I have never used it before and when I tried to use the color box, it said it wasn't defined.

The code is:

```
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="start(this)" class="inline">Start Here</button>

<div style="display:none" id="Set1">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="start(this)">Click here to open 2nd Set</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                Time Left: <span id="Time1"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="Set2">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="done()">Something else here</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                Time Left: <span id="Time2"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        //You could use colorbox here
        /*
        $(".inline").colorbox({
            inline: true,
            width: "1000",
            height: "850"
        }); 
        */
    }
    //This is the Question Number. It should start at zero.
    num = 0
    //This is a object where all the counters are going to be stored
    count = {}

    function Count(count,func,func2){
        /*
            This is an Object Constructor. This will hold all the timers and make
            it easier to create and kill a timer. The instanses will also hold the 
            data of the timer.
        */
        this.count = count
        thisParent = this

        this.kill = function(){
            //This is a function for stopping the timer
            clearInterval(thisParent.counter)
            if(func2 != undefined){
                //Calls the function when the timer ends.
                //The function was passed in as a argument
                func2()
            }
        }

        function oneCount(){
            //This function is executed every second

            //This function is passed in as an argument and is called every second.
            //The Parent Object is passed into it as the argument
            func(thisParent)

            //Decrements count
            thisParent.count -= 1

            //Stops timer at zero
            if(thisParent.count < 0){
                thisParent.kill()
            }
        }

        //This executes it once to prevent delay
        oneCount()

        //The counter is stored in ObjectInstance.counter
        this.counter = setInterval(oneCount,1000)
    }
    function start(el){
        num += 1
        max = 2
        element = document.getElementById("Set"+String(num))
        element.style.display = "block"


        if(num == 1){
            el.style.display = "none"
        }else{
            document.getElementById("Set"+String(num-1)).style.display = "none"
            count[num-1].kill()
        }

        element2 = document.getElementById("Time"+num.toString())
        function CountFunction(o,el){
            el.innerHTML = o.count
        }
        function End(){
            if(num<max){
                start(num+1)
            }
        }
        count[num] = new Count(3,function(n){CountFunction(n,element2)},End)
    }
    function done(){
        alert("That Was The Last Question")
    }
</script>
<body>
<html>
```

The URL is here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122705406/q.html

Comment: Thanks! Your code works great but I wanted to use colorbox because it lets me use a popup window where I put the 5 different tables with 5 different questions. Unless I could recreate a popup window?

Comment: You could use colorbox. I just couldn't. How did you get color box to work? I get that 'Undefined is not a function' when using colorbox.

Comment: Well, I haven't figured out how to make an automatic redirect once the countdown gets to zero. Works fine if the user actually clicks on the answer. (5 GameSets with 4 answers each). I made the href to #GameSet2 in my desperation of trying different options but nothing works haha. I kind of don't understand colorbox at all.

Comment: Is the $(".Set2").colorbox() {} really pointing to where I need to? Not sure how to relate all html "IDs" and colorbox.

Comment: You need to make the whole `div` containing the `style="display:none"` inline. Just setting the `.Set2` to inline will not make it visible

Comment: You mean like <div class='inline' style='display:none'> ? Well, this doesn't work either.